# How to get all properties of 'VEVENT' object?

Tags: javascript, icalendar

Is there any way to get some documentation about all existing properties of a VEVENT object (such as .summary or .start for example). For now I only know those below

```
if(data[i].type == 'VEVENT'){
   console.log(`${ev.summary} | ${ev.location} | ${ev.start.getDate()} ${months[ev.start.getMonth()]} | ${ev.start.toLocaleTimeString('en-GB')}`);
}
```

Comment: https://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/vevent.html

Comment: Also the 'official' version https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545